# Dryer is making a terrible sound

Tags: repair, dryer

Recently our dryer started making terrible noises. It sounds to me like a belt is broken, but it makes a grinding sound when turning. The noise is not constant. There is a strong burnt smell immediately after the noise starts.

https://youtu.be/7dFhoAvAqYg

The video shows my quandry. I would appreciate any help with the next troubleshooting steps.

The dryer is an NED7200TW Dryer and is several years old, probably 3 or 4.

This video might help a lot: https://youtu.be/7ErPT_QowkM
And this one might be very helpful as well (video of the motor running): https://youtu.be/hnVzpQQIvKo

Tim

Comment: ok -- now you can see a much better video -- is this definitely the motor? https://youtu.be/hnVzpQQIvKo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having a professional look at it, one of the wheels needed grease and the pulley was considered to be bad. The part cost $10 online, but the estimate to repair was $295.

Comment: Please select this as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the nylon drum guides have worn through.  I think those are inside the front and accessible by removing the front, which is tricky but fairly easy.

The sound could also be something (loose screw, sheet metal, shoelace) has worked its way into the mechanism somewhere.

Either way, some dis-assembly will provide answers.  From the sound, I would recommend not using it until it is fixed.

Comment: Will do -- going to do the disassembly today. I'll post what I find here.

Comment: How would I test for the nylon drum guides? please let me know if this video helps: https://youtu.be/7ErPT_QowkM

Comment: @bonhoffer:  Just look at them.  Compare them with a photo of a new one.  It seems that dryer does not use guides, but maybe the rollers [here](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/repair-parts-for-AMANA-NED7200TW10/1268/0151200.html).

Comment: any idea if I can confirm it is the motor from the videos above:  https://youtu.be/7ErPT_QowkM and https://youtu.be/hnVzpQQIvKo

Comment: i'm thinking it might be the motor because of the burnt smell

Comment: @bonhoffer:  Yikes!  Can you tell where the sound and smell come from?

Comment: no. i would just be guessing re: the sound.